# Pyscript: How to load a file via html input and passing it to Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyscript

I try to implement a webpage which has a button (file input dialogue) to load an Excel/ODF file and pass it to pandas for processing.

The problem is, that I do not have any glue how to pass the file (`f in fileList`) to `pandas.ExcelFile(...)`.

Here is the not fully working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    <title>File Example</title>

    <py-config type="json">
        {
        "packages": ["pandas"]
        }
    </py-config>

</head>

<body>
    <label for="file_input">Select a text file:</label>
    <input type="file" id="file_input" name="file_input">
    <br />
    <div id="print_output"></div>
    <br />
    <p>File Content:</p>
    <div style="border:2px inset #AAA;cursor:text;height:120px;overflow:auto;width:600px; resize:both">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
    <py-script output="print_output">
        import asyncio
        import pandas
        from js import document, FileReader, Uint8Array, console, TextDecoder
        from pyodide import create_proxy
        import io

        async def process_file(event):
            console.log('process_file()', event)
            fileList = event.target.files.to_py()
            for f in fileList:
                console.log('File:', f)
                data = Uint8Array.new(await f.arrayBuffer())
                data = TextDecoder.new().decode(data)
                efile = pandas.ExcelFile(data)
                console.log('Data:', efile.sheet_names)
                document.getElementById("content").innerText = data
            console.log('process_file()', 'end')

        def main():
            console.log('main()', 'start')
            # Create a Python proxy for the callback function
            # process_file() is your function to process events from FileReader
            file_event = create_proxy(process_file)
            # Set the listener to the callback
            e = document.getElementById("file_input")
            e.addEventListener("change", file_event, False)

            console.log('main()', 'end')

        main()
    </py-script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have an example for handling file input in an older blog post here: https://jeff.glass/post/pyscript-image-upload/ That was written back when PyScript was still on its Alpha release, so some of the syntax may be slightly different, but the Python should be essentially the same.